# com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom

Tags: java, casting, maven

Afetr using the Model library (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131365/is-there-a-java-class-that-generates-a-pom-xml-file)) for my Maven pom.xml during this weeks I jumped on this error while attempting to write a ConfiguratonContainer into the pom.xml.

The javadoc for Model says:

> public void setConfiguration(Object configuration)

```
Set the configuration as DOM object.

Parameters:
    configuration -
```

So I made some xml with Document (org.w3c.dom.Document) and the xml parser standar javax library. You know the code (it's through all the net) but I paste it here...

> ```
>           DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
> ```

```
            DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc =parser.newDocument();
```

And then you fill the code with Element declaration,a  lot of appendChild and such.

And tried to make it work. Doesn't seem to do well. 
First tried using

```
plugin.setConfiguration(doc);
```

But it didn't work. 
Then I tried

```
Obejct obj = doc;    
plugin.setConfiguration(obj);
```

But it didn't work.

Then I searched the net for answers, and guess...

It didn't work.

There are like 0 people using this library (maven.model) in all the net. So here am I again, asking the senseis for help.

Where is my error? I have downloaded the source code of the library trying to see where is the error, but it seems to be ok (as should).
I add the stackrace for reference

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom
at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Writer.writePlugin(MavenXpp3Writer.java:1472)
at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Writer.writeBuild(MavenXpp3Writer.java:326)
at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Writer.writeModel(MavenXpp3Writer.java:1093)
at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Writer.write(MavenXpp3Writer.java:102)
at com.mapfre.mutua.PDA.model.GeneratePOM.createPOM(GeneratePOM.java:28)
at com.mapfre.mutua.PDA.prueba.MavenPOM.generatePOMWAR(MavenPOM.java:681)
at com.mapfre.mutua.PDA.prueba.GenerarPOMMapfreAction.execute(GenerarPOMMapfreAction.java:36)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK problem solved (I promise never ever again ask something while I am on medication).

My main poblem was my inhability to understand that "Set the configuration as DOM object." (from the javadoc) was not refering to a DOM typical object, but a Xpp3Dom object.

Terribly sorry to make you loose your time.

By the way, seeming this leads to some kind of error, I suggest changing the javadoc so it is more understandable. Like "Set the configuration as Xpp3Dom object".