# How to call a maven mojo from java/scala using the maven-embedder

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-embedder

I want to call the help:effective-pom mojo directly from java/scala.

**Is there a minimal example how to setup the maven-runtime and call the mojo?**

I assume some context is needed before calling the stuff as supposed in the answer to this question:

[Reading POM's with its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855185/reading-poms-with-its-children)

e.g.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-help-plugin-2.1.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/help/EffectivePomMojo.java?view=markup

Specifically, the effective-pom mojo writes some ugly prefix and suffix to the xml which is not needed and I want to work directly on the xml later on.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. If i check the contents it has no garbage. The output will result into a single file. If you like to read the pom you should take a look at [aether lib](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/08/introducing-aether/), but the problem is that can read the pom with it but you would like execute a mojo instead which needs to build a Maven environment around which is very complex. Take a look [here to get an impression how it could look like](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-mojo-execution/tree/master/src/main/java/com/oneandone/devel/modules/pws/pwsp/embedder).

After some time I found [this which looks more](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) the thing you like to use.

Comment: That involves invoking a second JVM which will slow down things heavily. I have not only one file to parse but a big bunch of them. Further more, the output file contains garbage and possibly multiple files. Question is how to invoke it directly from a java program, without starting a new process.

Comment: Update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Maven Embedder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-embedder/index.html)/MavenCli

### Java code

```
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
cli.doMain(new String[]{"help:effective-pom"}, "project_dir", System.out, System.out);
```

### Project configuration

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```