# Performing arithmetic operations in pom file

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

Is it possible to perform arithmetic operations in pom.xml file? I need to generate an id based on the time and then divide it by 100. So I was wondering if I can do this division operation in the pom file.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you intend to do with the id?
You can use exec-maven-plugin for a script that calculates an id and writes this to some file. Maybe you can use  Properties Maven Plugin for reading the generated file.

Answer (score 2):

no operations are possible in pom.xml - but in your concrete case, you can use following properties:

- `maven.build.timestamp`
- `maven.build.timestamp.format`

to achieve the time-based value. Example:

```
...
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
...
   <configuration>
      <someproperty>${maven.build.timestamp}</someproperty>
   </configuration>
...
```

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns to format the resulting string. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to print only first digit of millis - but perhaps having just seconds could work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently thats what I am doing using the maven.build.timestamp but thats a temporary workaround.

Comment: It wasn't indicated on your question, so i considered this as the best workarround

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there are any arithmetic operation are permitted om the Pom.xml.

Instead you can try using this Using [MavenXpp3Reader](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader.html) and [MavenXpp3Writer](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Writer.html) to write new pom xml with your values in it.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131365/is-there-a-java-class-that-generates-a-pom-xml-file) will give you more insight on this...

Answer (score -1):

Someone has written a plugin that allows dynamic properties:
http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Properties-maven-plugin

Or someone else's attempt:
https://connect.gxsoftware.com/Blogs/Bram-de-Kruijff/Maven-secrets-Dynamic-Maven-properties-with-Beanshell.htm