# Expressing pom.xml with java annotations

Tags: java, maven

A wild idea just popped in my head to express a Maven project, which is described in pom.xml, with Java annotations in Java and generate "effective" pom.xml out of Java code with help of a maven plugin.

It looks like an obvious idea and most probably somebody tried to implement this and stepped on a pitfall, but I haven't found any attempt to do so on the  Internet. So I just curious to ask. :)

At first glance it's apparent thought, because Spring and even EJB started with XML and now where is it?! Maven reached version 3 years ago and I don't see any move away from XML.

I am aware of Gradle existence but it's completely different system with its own strong and weak points, I want a light restyle.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131365/is-there-a-java-class-that-generates-a-pom-xml-file?rq=1

Comment: My question is about links to the described plugin or explanation why it's bad idea and why such plugin nobody is going to found.

Comment: If XML is the problem, you might be interested in https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven.