# Is there a way to generate build.gradle file from Java programmatically

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy

I would like to know, how can I create gradle files from my Java project using some libraries as I could do it with maven ([Is there a Java Class that generates a POM.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131365/is-there-a-java-class-that-generates-a-pom-xml-file))

Does Gradle has some similar solution? Can somebody provide a solution how can I create my entire .gradle files from Java code?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Gradle has some similar solution?

Gradle does not provide a similar solution.